# how to get string value from a list in python

Tags: python

```
result = [{'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 20)}, {'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 21)}]
```

I want to get output like in list format:

```
result = ['2019-1-20', '2019-1-21']
```

Comment: `result = result[0]['start_date']`

Comment: Do you always want the first element or wait. do you want the result to be the first element of the list?

Answer (score 1):

Cast type to `str` :

```
result = str(result[0]['start_date'])
```

or

```
result = str(result[0].get('start_date']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code:

```
[print("Result :",Dict["start_date"]) for Dict in result]
```

Output:

```
Result : 2019-01-20
Result : 2019-01-21
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `strftime` to format your dates to what your desired form:

```
import datetime

result = [{'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 20)}, {'start_date': datetime.date(2019, 1, 21)}]

for date_val in result:
    print date_val['start_date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Results
2019-01-20
2019-01-21
```

If you want just the first element:

```
print result[0]['start_date'].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

See: [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) documentation